# How to extend side dock widgets vertically even when top/bottom docks are present?

Tags: qt, user-interface

Currently if I have `QDockWidget`s at the top, bottom and on the sides of my `QMainWindow`, they are arranged like this:

```
 _____________________
|                     |
|_____________________|
|   |             |   |
|   |             |   |
|   |             |   |
|___|_____________|___|
|                     |
|_____________________|
```

I'd like to have one of the side docks more extended vertically, like this:

```
 _____________________
|                 |   | 
|_________________|   | 
|   |             |   | 
|   |             |   | 
|   |             |   | 
|___|_____________|   | 
|                 |   | 
|_________________|___|
```

How can I do this with `QDockWidget`? I've tried looking at the various options in Designer, looked through all the documentation of `QDockWidget` and `QMainWindow` multiple times, but haven't found anything relevant. Do I have to create my own layout for this, or maybe subclass `QMainWindow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void QMainWindow::setCorner(Qt::Corner corner, Qt::DockWidgetArea area)`

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Tomas's answer. Qt documentation says:

> `void QMainWindow::setCorner ( Qt::Corner corner, Qt::DockWidgetArea area )`
>
> Sets the given dock widget `area` to occupy the specified `corner`.

It is in fact misleading: the area won't occupy *just* the specified corner. Rather this corner will *belong to* the area, i.e. you can set multiple corners to a single area, so you'd get e.g. side area at right with bottom-right corner, or with top corner, or with both.